# C++ Random Number Causing Crash when printing out value only. Very strange

Tags: c++, random, crash

I need a value between 0.0 and 1.0.  So I seed the random number generator using time.  Then I get a value between 0 and 10 using the rand function.  After that I take that value and divide it by 10 to get my decimal value.  My issues is that the program will randomly crash when I try and print out the value generated by (dRandNum % 10).  Also of note is that it is not crashing in the middle of the for loop.  It's always right at the beginning on the first attempt to print out.  I'm honestly thinking that there's just something really strange with the compiler and was wondering if anyone could direct me otherwise.

```
double dRandNum = 0;
int tempRand = 0;

/* initialize random seed: */
srand ( (unsigned)time(0) );


for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
      tempRand = rand();
      cout << "tempRand= " << tempRand << endl;
      dRandNum = tempRand % 10;// + 1;

      // Crashes here for some reason.  If I don't try and print the value it's fine
      cout << "Random Num Before " << i << ": " << dRandNum << endl;

      dRandNum = dRandNum / 10;
      cout << "Random Num After " << i << ": " << dRandNum << endl;
      weights[i] = dRandNum;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting that.  Here's a sample printout when it works.

tempRand= 13043
Random Num Before 1: 3
Random Num After 1: 0.3

Comment: @Geeklat I copypastad your code into VS 2010 and it worked fine. I have no idea why you're crashing. The tags "random crash" are doubly appropriate.

Comment: What do you mean by 'randomly crash', and what is the error message you receive?  And what platform are you on, and under what conditions is this code snippet running?

Comment: Have you tried running it a few times.  I'm really thinking it's a compiler issue.  I'm running DevC++ so it's off the G++ compiler.

Comment: @Geeklat If you take the mod  of a number n like this n % 10, then the result must be less than 10 (it is the remainder after division by 10). If you then go on to divide that result by 10, using integer arithmetic, you end up with zero.

Comment: @Geeklat I tried it 20 times on both debug and release builds and it never crashed. Do you have to use DevC++? I would recommend upgrading to VC++ or just using the latest version of g++.

Comment: @xtofl  Randomly crash as in it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't with no detectable pattern.  Windows Vista, DevC++, and this code is just a function that's part of a very simple C++ program.  For the sake of the program one can assume the function is wholly independent. The error is just the standard windows "This program has stopped working"

Comment: @Geeklat you should try running the program with Ollydbg (if you're on windows, which I assume you are) and see the place where the program is crashing. Or upgrade compilers.

Comment: @Geeklat Ignore all of these - you should POST MORE CODE!

Comment: @unaperson If you mod a number like 1234 by 10 the result is 4.  If you mod 567 by 10 the result is 7.  4 / 10 = 0.4    7 / 10 = 0.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For the sake of the program one can assume the function is wholly independent

That's a big mistake, it never is.  This has heap corruption written all over it.  Which rarely causes a crash at the line of the code that corrupts the heap.  Always later, sometimes much later.

Comment: Nice catch! I had a dynamically allocated array elsewhere that was off by 1 element.  Thanks gusto!

Answer (score 3):

OK, I'm going to take a random stab here and ask you to show us the declaration of the weights[] array.

And I'll even wager the traditional virtual jelly doughnut that weights[] is not declared to hold 40 elements.